# InvalidCastException in (int)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"));

Tags: c#, casting

I am trying to access the Event Code value (which is a unit) like this:

```
private static void EventLogMonitor(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
  ManagementBaseObject targetInstance = (ManagementBaseObject)e.NewEvent.GetPropertyValue("TargetInstance");
  EventId = (int)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"));
  ...
```

But I get an invalid cast exception at `(int)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"))`. It seems this piece of code returns an object, I wonder how it is possible to access the uint Event Code value?

Comment: For more information on this problem, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are dealing with `Win32_NTLogEvent` classes, you need to cast to `UInt16` (or `ushort`), as that is the type for "EventCode" according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394226%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
(UInt16)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should cast to unsigned int, not to int.

```
(uint)(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"))
```

**EDIT** Casting boxed values (i.e. through an `object`) requires knowing the exact type of the property, including if it is nullable or not, etc. Calling

```
targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode").GetType().FullNa‌​me
```

lets you find out the exact type.

Comment: @Jim What happened? Also try this: `Console.WriteLine(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode").GetType().FullName)`, this will show the exact type of the value inside the `object`

Comment: @Jim then you need to cast to `ushort`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Convert.ToUInt32(targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"))
```

Answer (score 0):

`targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode")` returns a boxed `ushort`.

There's a valid explict cast for turning a boxed `ushort` into a `ushort`:

```
ushort usVal = (ushort)boxUS;
```

There's a valid explicit cast for turning a `ushort` into an `int`:

```
int iVal = (int)ushortVal;
```

There's also a valid implicit cast for turning a `ushort` into an `int`:

```
int iVal = uShortVal;
```

But there's no valid implicit or explicit cast for turning a boxed `ushort` into an `int`:

```
int iVal = (int)boxUS; // throws exception.
```

But we can combine the above:

```
int iVal = (int)(ushort)boxUS;
int iVal2 = (ushort)boxUS;
```

Hence:

```
EventID = (ushort)targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"); //works
EventID = (int)(ushort)targetInstance.GetPropertyValue("EventCode"); //works and arguably clearer.
```

We can also use the `Convert` class, which is a tad more expensive and verbose, but handy in cases where there's a few possible types that the boxed value could be.